# Screen resolution of the app using ionic 1 framework

Tags: android, angularjs, iphone, cordova, ionic-framework

I have been facing a problem in the higher version of the moblie eg: Samsung version 9.0 in android  and Iphone X in Ios , There screen resolution are high, that i build the app using the ionic framework and cordova, when try to install on like that of  device the above and the below  i can see the black Patch, please suggest me how can i override by this problem

Answer (score 0):

Set **viewport** meta tag in the index.html file as follows:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover">
```

Ensure you go through the official Blog by Ionic Team on iOS 11 migrations. https://blog.ionicframework.com/ios-11-checklist/